# Bluetooth headphone sounds like in theater when plugged in

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headphones

My BT-233 bluetooth headphone when connected via bluetooth to my laptop sounds clear (it uses BT-233 Stereo for playback device, enhancements are turned off), but when I plug it in using the wires, the audio sounds like as if there's enhancements on (it now uses Speakers as playback device, there's no enhancements tab for Speakers), it sounds like I'm in a theater.

I also got another bluetooth Cliptec headphone that sounds clear when using wires (also uses the same Speakers as playback device when connected via wires)

I picked "headphones" when it asks what device I plugged in for both of the headsets.

Laptop has 1 headphone jack, has Realtek Audio Console app.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not, but have you checked their website or talked to the manufacturers support?

Comment: Welp the headphone was manufactured in China, and as far as I can see, there's no way to contact them for info on it.

Comment: In my experience when the ground connection of headphones are broken, it sounds "underwater" and the acoustics sound very *off* - perhaps the specific model has a broken ground connection where the physical wire input is? Aside from opening it up and having a look, consider getting it replaced under warranty.

Comment: @QuickishFM listening to music with the effect is fine for me, but I'd rather switch the effect out when playing games or talking to friends. I'm hoping to see if there are some settings that I might have missed that can turn it off, if not I can try to deal with it. (Hurts my ears quite a bit from listening for a long time with it compare to not having it at all)

Answer (score 0):

I turned "Limited Output" on in the Speaker's properties and the audio got less loud and I can hear better now.